# Как встроить свой код в модуль для Drupal?

Tags: drupal, база-данных, php, cms, обработка

Мне нужно ввести обработку данных(т.е. менять символы которые модуль записывает в БД). В cms Drupal, при считывание из cvs файла мне требуется менять некоторые символы. Данные из cvs пишет модуль feeds.

Пошарив по документации я понял, что мне нужно юзать [ссылка](https://web.archive.org/web/20180527021532/http://www.drupalcontrib.org:80/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/7) и колдовать над функцией ***hook_feeds_presave()***

В файле **feeds.api.php** есть код:

```
<?php ....
function hook_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item) {
  if ($entity->feeds_item->entity_type == 'node') {
    // Skip saving this entity.
    $entity->feeds_item->skip = TRUE;
  }
}
....
?>
```

Моя функция на php не большая:

```
<?php

function LaTexFormat($str)
{
    $tr = array(
        "\sqrt"=>"корень",
    );
    return strtr($str,$tr);
}

?>
```

Как её встроить в код, что бы перед записью в БД она обрабатывалась моей функцией.

Спасибо.

**Ps** С *php* поверхностно знаком.

Comment: Перефразирую:  
Какую переменную обработать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта задача решается через плагины к [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). [Пример в документации](https://www.drupal.org/node/1246602)
Пишете кастомный плагин, добавляете его всписке плагинов при обработке импорта и все. Но, скорее всего вам будет достаточно одного из стандартных плагинов уже присутствующих в модуле.

Comment: этот модуль обрабатывает фиды используя hook_feeds_after_parse(), вы бы сразу сказали, что хотите решение мышкой накликать,ибо для вас написание одной функции и ее отладка - непосильная задача

Answer (score 2):

ну так вроде же на друпалру вам уже объяснили, что нужно написать небольшой модуль, для этого
в каталоге /sites/all/modules/ создаете папку feeds_strtr (получиться /sites/all/modules/feeds_strtr)
внутри этой папки создаете :
файл feeds_strtr.info

```
name = feeds_strtr
description = My custom feeds manipulations
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = feeds
package = Custom modules
```

файл feeds_strtr.module

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_presave().
 */
function feeds_strtr_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item){
  dpm($source); // для использования dpm нужнен модуль devel
  dpm($entity);
  dpm($item);
}
```

Смотрите что содержится в переменных и нужное пропускаете через свою функцию